# Cannot compile boost::condition_variable cond_

Tags: gcc, boost, compiler-errors, conditional-statements, inter-process-communicat

*I have a class with the following -*

**boost::condition_varaible cond_;**

*When I try and compile  -*
**[rmitra@butterfly boost]$ make EXE=thread_safe_stack

g++    -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_thread -o thread_safe_stack thread_safe_stack.cpp**

*I get the following error -*
thread_safe_stack.cpp:25: error: ‘condition_varaible’ in namespace ‘boost’ does not name a type

thread_safe_stack.cpp: In member function ‘void thread_safe_stack::push(const T&)’:

thread_safe_stack.cpp:34: error: ‘cond_’ was not declared in this scope

thread_safe_stack.cpp: In member function ‘void thread_safe_stack::pop(T&)’:

thread_safe_stack.cpp:42: error: ‘cond_’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [exe] Error 1

*Please explain what the problem is.. I am using boost 1.54

I have the following headers included in my source file -*

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/exceptions.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: This is how I compile -

Comment: g++    -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_thread -o thread_safe_stack thread_safe_stack.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're spelling `condition_variable` wrong:

```
boost::condition_varaible cond_;
                    ^^
```

Comment: Hi Carl, Appreciate your help on this....I should know better than to work at 1 AM...

Comment: No problem, I hope it got you unblocked.